# how to override login authentication process of WSO2 ldap/AD

Tags: ldap, wso2-identity-server

Hi All I m current using the WSO2 identity server as authentication and authorization of user(which is inside the LDAP/AD) so my question is how to override the login authentication
my own way(WSO2 v5.8 )

Comment: Based on the context of the question I think https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Writing+a+Custom+Local+Authenticator would guide you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to change the User authentication flow process, first one is using a custom authenticator and the next one is using the adaptive script, they are two different functionalities provided in WSO2IS.

**1. Writing Custom Authenticator**
[[https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Writing+a+Custom+Local+Authenticator]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Writing+a+Custom+Local+Authenticator)
The custom authenticator is normally written to apply a new function as an example if you want to authenticate the user with a mobile number instead of a username and password, So you can create a custom authenticator to authenticate the user with a mobile number.

**2.Adaptive Authentication**
[[https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Adaptive+Authentication]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Adaptive+Authentication)
Adaptive authentication is to change the Authentication order and functionalities between the authentication process.So you can change and add custom functionalities you want to apply in the adaptive authentication process.